# Showing that a power series is identically zero.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series

I'm having serious trouble with this problem. Supposedly, Rolle's Theorem is supposed to be used to prove this. I understand how Rolle's Theorem is relevant, but I don't know how to use it to prove this statement.

Let

$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} (x - x_{0})^{n} , | x - x_{0} | < R
$$
and $f(t_{n}) = 0$ where $t_{n} \neq 0$ and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} t_{n} = x_{0}$. Show that $f(x) \equiv 0$ (when $| x - x_{0}| <  R)$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: The question is about a real valued function and the OP does not seem to know much apart from the Rolle's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality let $x_0=0$. We prove by induction that for every $k=0,1,2,\ldots$, there is a sequence $s_n\to0$ Such that $f^{(k)}(s_n)\to0$. We are already given the base case $k=0$. (By passing to a subsequence we can always assume these sequences contain distinct values.) Now suppose we have the claim for some fixed $k$. Then Rolle’s theorem tells us that for every pair $s_n\neq s_{n+1}$, $f^{(k)}(s_n)=f^{(k)}(s_{n+1})$ implies there is an $s_n’$ in between such that $f^{(k+1)}(s_n’)=0$ (note importantly that since $f$ is analytic here it is smooth). By an easy $\frac\epsilon2$-type argument, $s_n\to0$ implies $s_n’\to0$.

To conclude, the existence of a sequence $s_n\to0$ such that $f^{(k)}(s_n)\to0$ Implies $f^{(k)}(0)=0$ by continuity of $f^{(k)}$.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how Rolle's theorem applies.

Let's assume $f \not\equiv 0$. Try to show the following: if $f(x_1) = 0$ for some $x_1$ then $f(x) = (x - x_1)^k g(x)$ for some integer $k > 0$ and power series $g(x)$ such that $g(x_1) \neq 0$.

Then by continuity, $g(x) \neq 0$ for $x$ sufficiently close to $x_1$ and thus $f(x) \neq 0$ for $x$ sufficiently close to $x_1$ (and $x \neq x_1$). This contradicts your hypothesis, can you see why?